# Compare screen width, height and load dynamic images without losing aspect ratio to fit all screen devices

Tags: android

I have been trying to achieve facebook image loading width and height, based on all screen size width and height in home page.

Below I have posted the code what I have been tried so far.

I have tried it in two ways:

**First way:**

**home_activity_layout.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     >

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_vertical_list"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/post_items_layout_middle_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

           <com.steve.thirdparty.ScalableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_posted_img_home"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/golive_load_image"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_user_posted_msg_post_items_home"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/cont_desc"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**ScalableImageView.java:**

```
public class ScalableImageView extends ImageView {

    public ScalableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScalableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScalableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Drawable d = getDrawable();
        if (d != null) {
            int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int h = w * d.getIntrinsicHeight() / d.getIntrinsicWidth();

            Log.e("Width", ""+w);
            Log.e("Height", ""+h);

            setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
        }
        else super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

But I haven't getting the expected result for different dimensions image.it won't exceed the height for higher density pixel images.

**Second Way:**

Get screen width and height and do some calculation:

```
 DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float screenHeight= displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
        float screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;


if(ImageHeight > ImageWidth)  
{ 
float scale = ImageWidth/ImageHeight
float screenWidth = 320 (for example)
float getHeight = screenWidth /scale  


}
```

in this way, very height density pixel images are not showing in home page.

Anyone can help me with this.Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue in **two** ways :

**First Way:**

I had made some changes with ImageView.I removed external class for imageview.Using imageview `width` and `height` to wrap content made image view fit to all screen devices using `adjustviewbounds`.

```
 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/iv_posted_img_home"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     android:scaleType="fitStart"
     android:src="@drawable/load_image"
     android:layout_below="@+id/tv_user_posted_msg_post_items_home"
     android:contentDescription="@string/cont_desc"/>
```

**Note :** Using width and height wrapcontent will cause memory out of error.

**Second Way:**

This solution is a safest solution to not exceed out of memory error.

In json response,I'm getting the width and height of the imageview.So I'm handling all the imageview in adapter using width and height.

**Adapter Code:**

```
    if(rowItem.getWidthImage() != null){

                   if(rowItem.getWidthImage().equals(null) || rowItem.getWidthImage().equals("")){

                       Log.e("InvalidImage", "Test");

                   }else {

                       Log.e("imageWidth", ""+rowItem.getWidthImage());
                       Log.e("imageHeight", ""+rowItem.getHeightImage());

                       int imageWidth = Integer.parseInt(rowItem.getWidthImage());
                       int imageHeight = Integer.parseInt(rowItem.getHeightImage());


                       DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
                       ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

                       int width = dm.widthPixels;
                       int height = width * imageHeight / imageWidth; 

                       params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);

                       holder.ivPostedImageNew.setLayoutParams(params);
                       holder.llPostedImage.addView(holder.ivPostedImageNew);


                       Glide.with(context).load(rowItem.getPosteduserpostimage()).placeholder(R.drawable.golive_load_image).error(R.drawable.bg_golive).into(holder.ivPostedImageNew);


                   }


               }
```

For more details : Refer [here](http://helpjavaandroidbeginers.blogspot.in/2016/10/load-images-without-reducing-aspect.html)